# Will Wall of Light Kills count as your kill?

Tags: dishonored

There are achievements that require not killing any enemy during a mission or even the whole game.

But, also, there are parts of the game where you can rewire the Walls of Light in order to be able to pass through them. The downside is that, if a guard passes, he will be obliterated.

Will this count towards a kill for you, ruining the achievement ?

I know i can remove tha whale oil from the reactor, deactivating the wall by the way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**, kills with Wall of Lights will count as *your* kill.

> Kills by Rewired traps will contribute to your kill amounts and Chaos;
>   that’s Watchtowers, Arc Pylons, and Wall of Lights.

<sup>Source: [Notes on Stealth Detection, Chaos, and Trophies/Achievements by Gstaff (Bethesda Community Manager)](https://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1415445-notes-on-stealth-detection-chaos-and-trophiesachievements/)</sup>